# Can Scrap Booker be replaced with Evernote in Air Command on Galaxy Note 3?

Tags: evernote, samsung-galaxy-note-3, s-pen

> Scrap Booker – save anything you encounter – such as websites, maps, and pictures – into organized scrapbook categories with accompanied notes and information for later browsing. (from Phandroid Galaxy Note 3 review).

What makes this special is that it's quick accessibility from Air Command menu that is activated via S-Pen.

But functionality wise, this seems like an equivalent of (or subset of) Evernote.

On one hand, as an Evernote user, I'd love to NOT have to have parts of my data in a separate scrapbooking application. On the other, Air Command menu and S-Pen integration is a big win.

As such: Is there any way to integrate Evernote with this scrapbooking functionality in Note 3?

I'm fine with any solution (e.g. full on replacement by Evernote, or even something as simple as a way to import 100% of my current Scrap Booker data into Evernote).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't replace anything on air command.

If your phone is rooted, then there might be an app that allows this, however, I know of none.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Evernote is one of the share menu options from scrapbook. If you share the text and images of a scrap note, it will share to Evernote as any other note.

Comment: But does this apply to the "Air Command" feature of the Note 3?